# Xcode error .zprofile:1 and The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock MacBook m1 flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, sandbox

When I want to start an exist flutter project in Xcode I get this error with an error in my terminal. I use MacBook M1:

```
Showing Recent Messages
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your        CocoaPods installation.
```

When I start the terminal, I get this error:

```
/Users/wernergast/.zprofile:1: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/wernergast/.zprofile:2: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/wernergast/.zprofile:3: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/wernergast/.zprofile:4: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

I try this in the terminal:
Option 1.
To Fix Type nano .zprofile then delete all of the stuff then do ⌃X then press return
Then is the error in the terminal gone, but I think that this is not working for my    project

Option 2

```
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/wernergast/.zprofile
```

The error is back when I restart the terminal

Option 3
I removed libPods
I try to update cocoapods -> didn't work

Option 4
Update pods -> not exist

I don't get an error in a new project (Xcode), only in the template that I use.
I'm really stuck for 3 days, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was working for me.
In the project root:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
pod update
```

If the project already exist: Set the base configuration of the target runner.